# How to get value from a html table?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to get information from the following site: http://www.ebi.ac.uk/intact/, then search Q9SUE8. Using urllib I get the html of the page:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
url = 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/intact/'
values = {'queryTxt':'Q9SUE8'}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
print the_page
```

When searching Q9SUE8 from the browser it gives the following table as a result:

```
#    Molecule 'A'    Links 'A'    Molecule 'B'    Links 'B'    some more columns
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    T13J8.10        Q9SUE8       GRF7            Q96300
                     EBI-4459886
```

I want to extract the value Q96300. I can find the column headers back in the html:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <input id="mainPanels:columnSelection:3" type="checkbox" name="mainPanels:columnSelection" checked="checked" value="moleculeB.links" />
    <label for="mainPanels:columnSelection:3">&#160;Links 'B'</label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I'm not familiar with html but I guess that Q96300 comes from value="moleculeB.links". How can I get that value?

Comment: I am so sorry if I'm chiming in a little over my head but, are you trying to get the value of a given element that you have either a class or id or index information from?

Comment: As far as I can see I only have an input id, but I've never really worked with javascript so I don't know

Comment: If you have an the id of the input element, it is super easy.  I'll post an answer below.

Comment: I took out the javascript tag, your issue doesn't have to do with javascript

Comment: @jedwards I took it a step further and removed all references to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you need to worry about the javascript.  It's likely it's a session/hidden input issue.

But the following code works:

```
import mechanize
import re

b = mechanize.Browser()

# Visit search page
url = 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/intact'
resp = b.open(url)
page = resp.read()

# Fill out and submit form
b.select_form(name="intactForm")
b["queryTxt"] = 'Q9SUE8'
resp = b.submit()
page = resp.read()

# Parse Page
matches = re.findall('<td role="gridcell" class="cellTextCompound"><div class="ui-dt-c"><a href=".*?" target="_blank">(.*?)</a>', page)

linksB = matches[0]
print linksB
```

Output:

```
Q96300
```

Note that it requires the [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) module (available in the Fedora repo as `python-mechanize`).

Comment: Why does he need this much code to simply read one value? You should simplify your answer to something workable.